# I go through waves, not quite a sea

Tags: riddle

I go through waves, not quite a sea.
I look for more, hope to find none.
If my job were done, so would be carelessness.
Who am I?

EDIT: due to the puzzle being vague, I have closed this down.

> A fire man is correct, Waves of flame, I hope not to find any, carelessness is the cause of several fires.

I'm sorry for this one being a flop! I will make a more 'direct' puzzle next time.

Comment: Tiny hint= Maybe not the waves you're thinking of. Figuritive waves, waves of something. And remember who NOT what.

Comment: Don't be shy to answer! My riddle has a very broad meaning, and could be interpreted any way! Remember it's a person, not a thing!

Comment: Is it somehow a crowd surfer?

Comment: Not quite... Not sea waves, I'll give you that... Perhaps the opposite...

Comment: re "could be interpreted any way": In general, we want puzzles to have a single, verifiable solution. Please consider [reworking your puzzle to clear up ambiguity](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6983/69582).

Comment: I agree bobble, I was thinking about that too. I'm going to upvote the closest one! Thank you for cronstructive critism for my first puzzle!

Comment: Please, fellows, no need to down vote. This puzzle has been solved.

Comment: You should post your answer to the question as an actual answer and accept it, instead of editing it into the question and then accepting an answer that by your own admission is incorrect.

Comment: The reason I chose that answer is because my puzzle was vague, so I picked the one that fitted this riddle the closest. In all due respect, this is my puzzle. I will manage it the way I please to do, and will accept constructive critism. I will keep your comment in mind for future puzzles. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> **A lifeguard**?

I go through waves, not quite a sea.

> Rescuing people in danger of drowning at beaches or big swimming pools

I look for more, hope to find none.

> A lifeguard's job is to be on the lookout for people in trouble, but finding one is always a bad thing

If my job were done, so would be carelessness.

> Nearly all danger situations at beaches and swimming pools are caused by careless behaviour of one kind or another.

Comment: Close! That would be another job, but still not quite yet! keep guessing!

Comment: "Matching all the clues is not enough, you also have to guess what I was thinking" can be a fun face-to-face activity, when extra clues and hints can be dropped at will. On Stack Exchange however, changing the question after answers have been given conflicts with the site's fundamental design, so this approach is strongly discouraged. (It's actually one of the few reasons why a question might get closed here.)

Comment: I agree bass, I am quite the rookie ;). I'll try my best next time!

Answer (score 4):

probably not the right answer, but am i

> ***shock***?
>  - *shock*wave is a word
>  - when you're shocked (surprised), you look for more, but hoping for no more surprises
>  - people who are in shock tend to act carelessly

Comment: That's good, but not quite the answer! You're on the right track!

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking radar.

> Because radar travels in waves and not quite a sea means that although it is not a sea wave it is nevertheless a wave in the sea.

> They can check more and more of the surroundings in hope of not finding danger.

> If they don't detect any danger the people in the submarines could be lulled into a false sense of security. They might socialize rather than pay attention to the radar screen or periscope.

Comment: Almost, remember, Who not what

Comment: That was not stated in the initial question

Comment: I'm sorry, I though I made it clear when I said "Who am I". I'll try to make my riddles more specific in the future. You can always guess again!